# Can you scale SQL Server to handle 100's of Terabytes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

One of my colleagues told me the other day SQL Server wasn't designed to handle Terabytes of data.....that could possibly be true for SQL 2000 or any DB 10 years ago, but I don't believe that to be the case today.  How have others approached the situations where they need to store massive amounts of data (100 + Terabytes)? Growing one Single server is probably not the option, but I would think we could partition the data across many smaller servers and use views, etc to allow us to make one query call across the servers.  Any idea how concurrency, etc performs in a model like this where data is Horizontally Partitioned across servers?

Any suggestions / comments is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Comment: To the closers: You've selected an option which says "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise". The answer to this question involes 3/3 of those criteria.

Comment: It also says "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.", which is true for this question.

Comment: @Don seems like a pretty specific question about server limitations and capabilities to me, not an attempt to incite a religious debate.

Comment: @Don - you think so? Opinion - nope (MS publish the spec), debate - unlikely for the same reason, aguments - if you want to argue MS is wrong about their own product feel free, polling - not sure what that means, extended discussion - I doubt it, this seems like a pretty cut and dry issue.

Comment: Well then, perhaps we should just be voting for migration to serverfault where it would at least be on-topic.

Comment: Microsoft's answer to 100s x Terabyte workloads is SQL Server PDW. (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/data-warehouse.aspx). It doesn't succeed in my opinion but that's what it is *supposed* to be designed for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether it's *designed to* handle that size is a matter of potential debate. If you want the cold hard facts of what is *possible* then read on.

According to [the specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) published by Microsoft, SQL Server 2008 R2 (32 and 64 bit versions) has a maximum database size of 524,272 terabytes. This is the same for SQL Server 2008, and SQL 2005 it's 524,258 terabytes.

See, they made an improvement, from 2005 to 2008 you can have an extra 14 Terabytes in your database :)

Comment: +1 Thank you for answering the question clearly with facts. It did not lead to opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.